# route deviation in leaflet ( openstreet ) maps

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

I am new to leaflet and openstreet maps. I have a starting location, ending location and a few way points in between.

I will also get the current position of the vehicle every 20 seconds. Now I need to findout whether the vehicle is going along the proposed route.

I have done these kind of things in google and HERE maps. But i couldn't find any documentation about route deviation in leaflet/OSM maps.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Regards,
tvarghese

Comment: Please post some code so we can help